# Should I create a ViewModel for each item in an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, revit-api

Being fairly new to MVVM in WPF I am running into a dilemma of what items need their own ViewModel. I am writting a plugin for Autodesk's Revit program. Using the provided API I am drilling into the parameters of elements and performing engineering calculations in a way that is easier for the end user to understand. I have outlined my approach in the image below.

[image: Data Flow Method]

The element is a model element in the program that is selected manually. An instance of the FPB class is then created by pulling parameters from the element and assigning them to the FPB's properties. The ViewModel contains an ObservableCollection that contains a list of FPB objects the user has selected. Using a combobox the user can select which FPB they want to edit. The WPF page then shows the respective values for the properties that the user needs to interact with to perform their engineering calculations.

Using WPF's databinding the values can be changed in the View and the value is subsequently changed in the ViewModel's FPB in the ObservableCollection. In order to write these values back to the Element in Revit the change needs to be raised in the API's ExternalCommand and ensured in a transaction. It then executes a method that writes the values back to Revit.

My issue is for each value changed in the view the data needs to update the element. This element is performing its own calculations that are changing the data values. These updated value then need to return all the way back to the view. The round trip is shown below.

View -> ViewModel -> FPB in ObservableCollection -> *Update Element* -> FPB in ObservableCollection -> ViewModel -> View

To adhere to MVVM principles do I need to create a FPBViewModel for each FPB instance? Will this allow for an easier flow of data? Or is this just unnecessarily complicating the data flow. I can add code snippets if need be, but this appears to be more of a theory question than code specifics question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "do I need to create a FPBViewModel for each FPB instance" -- very often you do; there's often a need for such objects to raise change notifications, and it's standard practice for them to do so. If you see a need, don't sweat the complexity. However, if you just let the user edit some properties that don't know about each other, and then the user clicks "Save" and you push the changes to an API, you may be able to get away with leaving it a POCO class. The "viewmodel wrapped around a model" pattern involves a lot of drone work.

Comment: If you want your FPB to have a live-updated `IsDirty` flag, for example, to enable the Save button -- that's a viewmodel (on initialization, have it save a private "clean" clone of the FPB POCO for comparison on property changes). Calculated fields, stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Just to make sure I get the gist of your answer. You are recommending making a FPBViewModel class to wrap the FPB model, and then instead of creating an ObservableCollection of FPB objects, create a ObservableCollection of FPBViewModels? This would then change my bindings to properties within the FPBViewModel correct? Would I then need to add a command in the FPBViewModel to push the changes and then receive the updated values back to the POCO FPB in the FPBViewModel?

Comment: I'm not convinced you need an FPBViewModel, but I don't know the details of your project. If you are persuaded that it'll add value, go for it; it's absolutely standard MVVM vernacular. Everything else you say is correct. The FPB POCO becomes a sort of intermediate format for communicating to and from the data layer. It's the "model" in "Model-View-ViewModel". P.S. Also what Andy says. There's more than one way to translate between the model and the viewmodel, and his suggestions are commonly used.

Comment: Wrappping is one way. Copying properties from model to viewmodel is another. You can use automapper or reflection iterating properties.

Comment: Do make sure that you don't just bind to some POCO classes you will likely run in to memory leak territory here (basically make sure that you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or inherit from `DependencyObject` on the class that is being bound).

Comment: [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)!